# Nexus Repository + Maven Snapshot vs Release NoClassDefError In one not other

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have an application that is a main JAR (HMI.jar) that I'm building via eclipse on my machine but it uses a maven dependency of another application of ours (WidgetLibrary.jar) that is posted up in Nexus 3 repo.

I build with maven but I have found that a NoClassDefError occurs against an item referenced from WidgetLibrary by the HMI. This only occurs when I build against a SNAPSHOT version of the WidgetLibrary using 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in the pom.

This error doesn't occur when I use a local version build from my eclipse into my local .m2 via Maven Install (using 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in pom). This doesn't occur when using a release build from nexus (using 1.0.0 in pom). This doesn't occur when I reference a snapshot build directly by it's timestamp version (1.0.0-20190813.192915-3 in pom). Note that I deployed the same WidgetLibrary jar to both release and snapshot (multiple times to test). There is no difference between the jars other than timestamp. The issue solely happens when I use the nexus snapshot repo and reference the generic 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and it has to link up the the timestamped version in nexus.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on??

EDIT WITH NEW INFO: OK, I found that the problem is that maven is placing the jar in the lib folder when building the main hmi jar and renaming it the regular widgetlibrary-1.0.0-snapshot but it is putting the widgetlibrary-1.0.0-timestamp-iterate name in the manifest classpath. I fixed the issue by manually adding the correct name to the classpath. Why is maven screwing this up?

Comment: Have you completely deleted your local repository and tried again?

Comment: Not completely. But I have deleted the component. This also happens when built via our Jenkins build server which completely deletes the workspace and local repo every build.